# What's wrong with this closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm beginning to learn iOS development with Swift. I'm watching Stanford University's lessons on iTunes U and it starts by programming a calculator.

I use an Array of Doubles as stack of numbers. When a user click on an operation button, it calls a method named operate. To avoid code duplication, I did a function "performOperation" which takes another function (prototype: (Double, Double) -> Double) as parameter.

However, when I run my application, everything works until I try to perform an operation. Debugger stops in performOperation method and I don't know what's wrong with my code. I tried to compare it with the teacher's one, but I didn't find any difference.

Here is the complete code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
    var userHasStartedToTypeANumber: Bool = false
    var operandStack = Array<Double>()

    @IBAction func touchDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if userHasStartedToTypeANumber {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
            userHasStartedToTypeANumber = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func enter() {
        userHasStartedToTypeANumber = false
        operandStack.append(displayValue)

        print("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        if userHasStartedToTypeANumber {
            enter()
        }

        switch sender.currentTitle! {
        case "＋": performOperation { $0 + $1 }
        case "−": performOperation { $1 - $0 }
        case "X": performOperation { $1 * $0 }
        case "÷": performOperation { $0 / $1 }
        default: break
        }
    }

    //Here is problematiek method ->
    func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double) {
        if operandStack.count >= 2 {
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
       }


    }

    var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }

        set {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userHasStartedToTypeANumber = false
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I'm conscient some parts of this code are terrible and that calculations shouldn't be done in this controller class, this is a deliberate choice. I wouldn't do that in a real application.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Did you accidentally set a breakpoint?  Is there a blue arrow in the gutter to the left of the line you are stopping on?  If so, control click on it and delete it.

Comment: @vacawama I can't believe I did this mistake... That's so stupid! Thanks for this obvious answer.  :)